# Swift Post Special and Foreign characters

Tags: xcode, swift, post

For the posting I am using

```
 var post = "content=\(message)&post=\(time)"
```

But when I enter something like € for variable message, I get this error: 
fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
(lldb)

When there are no special characters it works and I get back:
2015-02-04 15:38:16.918 sdfff[12306:60b] Response code: 200
2015-02-04 15:38:16.920 sdfff[12306:60b] Response ==> {"success":1}

Comment: That looks relevant. But, it is also an answer in Objective-C.

Comment: String is not identical to NSString?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding when using special charactheres in your NSURL as follow:

```
var post = "content=€&post=€".stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)!

println(post)  // "content=%E2%82%AC&post=%E2%82%AC"


var revert = "content=%E2%82%AC&post=%E2%82%AC".stringByRemovingPercentEncoding!
println(revert) // "content=€&post=€"
```

Comment: @Teb Theestatebook Thank you

Comment: Is there a way to convert it back, not critical, just curious.

Comment: Yes you can use stringByRemovingPercentEncoding

Comment: Do you know how I can do this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28332760/location-manager-in-background-swift