# swift 2 character "&" cannot upload in http POST Request

Tags: php, mysql, swift2

I am trying to send some string to mysql through PHP which the string include some special characters, such as "&,?,/".
The problem is all the string which after the character "&" will be missed. 
for example, the string "Ak-47&Bomber" will be send in "Ak-47".

Swift:

```
 let url: NSURL = NSURL(string: "MyPhP.php")!
        let session = NSURLSession.sharedSession()

        let request:NSMutableURLRequest = NSMutableURLRequest(URL:url)
        request.HTTPMethod = "POST"
        request.cachePolicy = NSURLRequestCachePolicy.ReloadIgnoringCacheData

        let bodydata = "String=\(Ak-47&Bomber)"
        request.HTTPBody = bodydata.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)

        if bodydata != " " {

            let task = session.dataTaskWithRequest(request) {
                (data, response, error)  -> Void in

                let httpResponse = response as! NSHTTPURLResponse
                let statusCode = httpResponse.statusCode
```

PHP :

```
$String= ($_POST["String"]); // the String i got "Ak-47"
$sql =  "INSERT INTO table (string) VALUES ('" .
            $String."' )";
        $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
```

any solution?

Comment: You need to urlencode the data.

Comment: i have tried,  `let str = Ak-47&Bomber`     `let str2 = str.stringByAddingPercentEncodingWithAllowedCharacters(NSCharacterSet.URLFragmentAllowedCharacterSet())`  `let bodydata = "String=\(str2)"`, however, it is not working.

Comment: i have also tried `$String= htmlspecialchars($_POST["String"]);`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28331094/swift-post-special-and-foreign-characters

Comment: NOW i use `stringByAddingPercentEncodingWithAllowedCharacters`, it is done, buti don't know how to decode it.

Comment: i fail to decode the string by using `bystringByRemovingPercentEncoding` which encoded by `stringByAddingPercentEncodingWithAllowedCharacters`